# kendo editor : immutables can be deleted -- how to prevent that

Tags: kendo-ui, editor

Immutables can't be edited but they can be deleted. Is it possible to prevent that?

If the immutable is selected it can be deleted, or if the cursor is placed right after the word and the user hits ENTER, gone.

https://jsfiddle.net/hrg6n2wh/

```
 $("#keditor").kendoEditor({
                //handles: "se"
                resizable: { content: true, min:100},
                tools: [],
                value: '<p contenteditable="false" style="color:blue; font-size: large">Section1</p><p></p>' +
                '<p contenteditable="false" style="color:blue; font-size: large">Section2</p><p></p>' +
            '<p contenteditable="false" style="color:blue; font-size: large">Section3</p><p></p>' +
            '<p contenteditable="false" style="color:blue; font-size: large">Section4</p><p></p>' +
           '<p contenteditable="false" style="color:blue; font-size: large">Section5</p><p></p>',
            immutables:true
            });
```

ENTER also does not inject a carriage return and "open up" a space for text to be typed in; rather it can send the insert position back to the top of the document.

It depends on precisely where the insert caret is placed. If the user carefully positions the insert pointer between the immutables, then text can be entered.

Can that behavior be tweaked?

Comment: Hi, were u able to find a solution for this ? I am facing the same issue..